# CDF of a log-concave discrete random variable

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, probability-distributions, large-deviations

In the continuous setting, it's known that if a density function is log-concave , then its CDF is also log-concave.

My questions:

1. What can we say about this in the discrete setting?. For ex: Is the CDF of a Poisson random variable log-concave?.

My 2nd question could be somewhat relevant to above.

2. If $X \sim Pois(\lambda)$ , then a large deviation bound $P(X \geq x)$ makes sense only when $x\geq \lambda$. Is there a way to come up with a bound for $x< \lambda$ (or extend the bound for this case)?

Any comments on this would be appreciated (including references).

Comment: The first question makes no sense since the CDF of a Poisson random variable is not continuous.

Comment: @user64494 That's why I mentioned 'discrete'. log-concave in the sense of discrete log-concavity

Comment: Like, in the discrete setting, if PMF is log-concave ,then is it true that its CDF is also log-concave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, if the probability mass function of an integer-valued random variable is log concave as a function on $\mathbb Z$, then the corresponding cdf is also log concave as a function on $\mathbb Z$.

This is a special case of [Theorem 2, p. 152](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Advances_in_Stochastic_Inequalities/oksbCAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA149&printsec=frontcover). This answers your first question.

---

As for your second question, it is rather unrelated to the first one. So, it is better to post it separately. Generally, I think posting multiple questions in one post should be avoided.

Comment: Thank you sir!. I'm referring to theorem 2. In the case of Poisson, we can choose $q(n) = e^{-\lambda} \lambda^n /n!$ and $r=\infty$ . But, which $\alpha$ would make $\mathcal{J}^\alpha q$ the CDF of Poisson?

Comment: @SL_MathGuy : To get the CDF of the Poisson distribution (that is, its left tail), take $\alpha=1$ and "read the the probability mass function right-to-left"; that is, take $q(n)=e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{-n}1(n=0,-1,-2,\dots)/(-n)!$.