# Upper bound for $P(X \geq x)$, where $X \sim \operatorname{Pois}(\lambda)$

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, probability-distributions, large-deviations

I posted the following question in a [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/383007/cdf-of-a-log-concave-discrete-random-variable/383016#comment974227_383016) on [CDF of a log-concave discrete random variable](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/383007/cdf-of-a-log-concave-discrete-random-variable/383016). Since it is not related to my main question, I thought of reposting it as separate post.

**Question:**

Let $X \sim \operatorname{Pois}(\lambda)$. I'm interested in a large deviation bound for $X$; more specifically a sub-exponential type bound for $P(X \geq x)$ for all $x\geq 0$. While it's known that such a bound exists for $x \geq \lambda$ (Chernoff bound), it's not clear whether there exists one for $x< \lambda$. Is it possible to obtain a bound (or extend the bound obtained for $x \geq \lambda$) for these $x$ values using standard large-deviation techniques? If not, why not?

Comment: When $x<\lambda$, the event $\{X \ge x\}$ holds with at least constant probability, so we are not in the large-deviations regime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand\Ga\Gamma\newcommand\Z{\mathbb Z}\DeclareMathOperator\Pois{Pois}$Let $t\mathrel{:=}\lambda$ and $k\mathrel{:=}x\in\Z\cap[0,t)$. Then for $X_t\sim \Pois(t)$ we have
$$P(X_t\ge k)=1-\frac{\Ga(k,t)}{\Ga(k)};$$
this can be shown e.g. by integrating
$$\Ga(k,t)=\int_t^\infty u^{k-1}e^{-u}\,du$$
$k-1$ times by parts.

It follows now by Corollary 3 of [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.spl.2020.109027) or its [arXiv preprint version](http://arxiv.org/abs/2012.13578) that $P(X_t\ge k)>1/2$. Therefore (as was [noted](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/383110/upper-bound-for-px-geq-x-where-x-sim-pois-lambda#comment974436_383110) by user J.), standard large-deviation techniques are not applicable here.

However, using Theorem 1.1 and Proposition 2.7 of [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.7153/mia-2020-23-95) or its [arXiv preprint version](https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.06384), we have
$$P(X_t\ge k)\le B_1(k,t)\mathrel{:=}1-e^{-t} \Big(1+\frac{(t+2)^k-t^k-2^k}{2 k!}\Big)$$
for $k\ge3$ and
$$P(X_t\ge k)\le B_2(k,t)\mathrel{:=}1-\frac{e^{-t} t^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}$$
for $k\ge1$.

Both upper bounds, $B_1(k,t)$ and $B_2(k,t)$, on $P(X_t\ge k)$ are nontrivial, in the sense that they both are strictly less than $1$. Both bounds are rather accurate.
The bound $B_2(k,t)$ on $P(X_t\ge k)$ is simpler but less accurate than $B_1(k,t)$. What has been said in this paragraph is illustrated by the following graphs
$\Big\{\Big(k,\dfrac{P(X_{2k}\ge k)}{B_1(k,2k)}\Big)\colon k\in\{3,\dots,20\}\Big\}$ (red) and $\Big\{\Big(k,\dfrac{P(X_{2k}\ge k)}{B_2(k,2k)}\Big)\colon k\in\{3,\dots,20\}\Big\}$ (blue):

[image: graphs of relative errors for B_1 and B_2]

Here the maximum relative error of the bound $B_1(k,2k)$ on $P(X_{2k}\ge k)$ is $\approx0.001$ and the maximum relative error of the bound $B_2(k,2k)$ on $P(X_{2k}\ge k)$ is $\approx0.050$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll check out these papers.

Comment: I'm sorry for the delayed response but just wondering if the u.b when $k\geq 1$ should be $1- \frac{e^{-t} t^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}$ (NOT k!)?

Comment: @SL_MathGuy : That's right, it should have $(k-1)!$ in the denominator; this is now fixed. So, to have a closure, are you now satisfied with this answer?

Comment: I would say yes! I've accepted the answer. Thank you very much!